# how to convert word Ooxml to html using javascript?

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, add-in, office365api

`getHtml()` method doesn't return the exact same HTML for the same document on different platforms (Windows, Mac, Word on the web, etc.).  If you need exact fidelity, or consistency across platforms, use `Range.getOoxml()` and convert the returned XML to HTML.

**So question is how can I convert this Ooxml to html? using javascript**

[for more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.range?view=word-js-preview#word-word-range-gethtml-member(1))

[image: info image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are no method to convert html to Ooxml in JavaScript.